# jquery async function not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, cordova, backbone.js

I am creating my mobile application using cordova. when I got data from sqlite database it takes some time, that's why I am using deferred jquery. But I am not able to call function from $.when deferred jquery. I m so confused. Please help me.

```
callPaymentApi: function (e) {
    var loginDeferred = $.Deferred();
    var loginList = [];
    var dbLogin = new DBLogin();
    dbLogin.getLoginDetail(function (data) {
        loginList = data;
        loginDeferred.resolve();
    });
    $.when(loginDeferred).then(function success() {
        var email_id = loginList[0].email_id;
        var token_id = loginList[0].token_id;
        currTime = MyApp.getRequestTime();

        var data = {};
        data.request_time = currTime;
        data.token_id = token_id;
        data.email_id = email_id;
        console.log("data :::::::::: " + JSON.stringify(data));

        var net = MyApp.checkNetworkConnection();
        if (net == true) {
            $.blockUI();
            var urlRoot = String.baseURL + 'fetchdata';
            var loginModel = new Model();
            loginModel.urlRoot = urlRoot;
            loginModel.save(data, {
                success: function (response) {
                    $.unblockUI();
                    console.log("success ....." + JSON.stringify(response));
                    this.successHandler(response);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    $.unblockUI();
                    console.log("error ....." + JSON.stringify(response));
                    this.errorHandler(response);
                }
            });
        } else {
            navigator.notification.alert(l('%alert.internet.connection'), null, null, l('%common.OK'));
        }
    });
},
successHandler: function (response) { //Success handler 
    $.unblockUI();
    alert("success");
},
errorHandler: function (response) { //Success handler 
    $.unblockUI();
    alert("success");
}
```

I got data in log. REST API also working fine and got success response. But when I called function from success and error, it's not working. I can't able to call these functions "successHandler" & "errorHandler".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The context will be different inside the callbacks. You need to save the reference to current context, something like:

```js
callPaymentApi: function(e) {
    var that = this;
    ...
    $.when(loginDeferred).then(function success() {
      ...
      loginModel.save(data, {
        success: function(response) {
          ...
          that.successHandler(response);
        },
        error: function(response) {
          ...
          that.errorHandler(response);
        }
      });
    });
  },
  successHandler: function(response) { //Success handler 
    $.unblockUI();
    alert("success");
  },
  errorHandler: function(response) { //Success handler 
    $.unblockUI();
    alert("success");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's really helpful for me.